# jQuery - Form submit

Tags: jquery

I have a form that I intend to submit using jQuery. The following code works fine for the first time.

If the returning data equals "updated" I re-create the form within my #cart-content element. In other words: If i submit the form and it updates my cart I have a new form on my site (which has the same class, same inputs etc).

If I then click on submit again it wont trigger my jQuery code. I guess that because it's a new form that did not exist when the page was loaded so jQuery is not bound to its events and it doesnt get triggered when I submit the form.

What do I have to change to get it working? Thanks in advance!

```
$("form.update-cart").on("submit", function(event){
        $.post(link + "create_order/update_cart",  $(this).serialize(),  
        function(data){  
            if(data == 'updated')
            {
                var csrf_cookie = $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name');
                $("#cart-content").load(link + "create_order/display_cart", {"csrf_test_name": csrf_cookie});
            }
            else if(data == 'nothing-to-update')
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {  
                alert("Couldnt update cart!");  
            }  
        });  
        return false; 
});
```

Comment: Show us your html, are you replacing the whole form ? Why not just have another event handler bound using `.on` for the new form that is injected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to you and Catalin Ene, **[jQuery's "live" function is being deprecated from jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**.

You should use "`on`" function if you're using **jQuery 1.7.x** or later:

```
$("form.update-cart").on("submit", function(event) {
```

And you can use "`delegate`" if your **jQuery's** version is lower than 1.7:

```
$("form.update-cart").delegate("submit", "#submit_btn", function(event) {
```

**Also, an advice**: It's a good practice to use XML or JSON outputs from your server-side scripts.

- [Why need to use JSON in php and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881876/why-need-to-use-json-in-php-and-ajax)
- http://borkweb.com/story/the-case-for-json-what-is-it-and-why-use-it

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

`$("form.update-cart").live("submit", function(event){`

Answer (score -1):

I've figured it out but ill accept an answer as soon as i can. Thanks!

```
$(document).on("submit", "form.update-cart", function(event) {
        $.post(link + "create_order/update_cart",  $(this).serialize(),  
        function(data){  
            if(data == 'updated')
            {
                var csrf_cookie = $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name');
                $("#cart-content").load(link + "create_order/display_cart", {"csrf_test_name": csrf_cookie});
            }
            else if(data == 'nothing-to-update')
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {  
                alert("Konnte Warenkorb nicht aktualisieren!");  
            }  
        });  
        return false; 
});
```